# How to avoid segfault after calling deleteLater on pointer?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsscene

I have a `GraphicsScene:public QGraphicsScene` inherited class with a single `QGraphicsView` looking at it and `QTimer`, ticking to call function

```
void GraphicsScene::adv()
{
if (actor)
    views().at(0)->ensureVisible(actor,200,100);
advance();
}
```

`advance()` is an overriden method which is send to all `QGraphicsItem` objects on scene. The point of this function - I want to make sure `actor` is always visible. 
`actor` is a `unit:public QGraphicsPixmapItem` object on `GraphicsScene`.

At some point in `actor` method I call `deleteLater()`.

The next timer tick I receive `SEGFAULT` at `views().at(0)->ensureVisible(actor,200,100);` line

I wonder, why `if (actor)` passes as `true` after `deleteLater()` and what is the correct condition should I use?

Comment: If you delete an object your pointer points too, the pointer value doesn't automatically become null. Thus, even if object `actor` is deleted, the `if (actor)` still passes.

Answer (score 0):

> I have an object being asynchronically deleted by [deleteLater()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater%20/)
>   and wonder if there is a way to prevent accessing it from other
>   objects?

Yes, there is a way to tell programmatically whether or not the object was already deleted by using `QPointer<MyQObject>` as [described](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpointer.html). But that way is somewhat slow and your application code should rather have better logic to avoid that. Like, before calling `deleteLater` your code removes the reference for that object from, say, `views()` and your code should check for the view still there.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `deleteLater()` from inside your `actor`, the container `GraphicsScene` still has its pointer on it - the object itself doesn't reset all external pointers to it.

You have to reset this pointer - the member `actor` of your `GraphicsScene` to get your if-statement in `adv()` working.